# Creating a query that iterates through list of ids from table A inserting a new row in table B for each item

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am trying to implement a simple notification system that inserts "Notification" rows into a table "Notifications" for each user who has participated in a thread. The code I have takes place in a trigger and currently works on notifying a user that another user has responded to his specific comment, but does not notify everyone else in the thread that  a new comment has been posted.

```
ALTER TRIGGER OnDocumentCommentPosted
ON DocumentComments
AFTER
INSERT 
AS
IF (SELECT InResponseTo FROM inserted) IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
INSERT INTO Notifications
([CommentID],[Type],[RecieverId]) //This is a notification object from table Notifications shown at the bottom of this post
SELECT id, 'DocumentComment', InResponseTo //this is a DocumentComment object from table DocumentComments shown at the bottom of this post
FROM inserted
END
```

I basically want to grab the results from the below query and then run the same query above for each result.

```
SELECT OwnerId FROM DocumentComments WHERE DocumentID = @DocumentId
```

**gets me a list of ids**

*then for each id in list run the below query substituting each id into @id*

```
SET @Comid = (SELECT id FROM inserted);

INSERT INTO Notifications
([CommentID],[Type],[RecieverId])
@Comid, 'DocumentComment', @id
```

Is there a way to join this type of functionality into my original trigger query above?

**EDIT**

It seems this might be a bit confusing to comprehend so let me try to explain my table structure simply

**Brief explanations**

Table: Documents - (Holds the actual data for excel, pdfs, whatever is uploaded via users)

Table: DocumentComments - (Holds comments made on each document [One - Many])

Table: Notifications - (Holds notification data for each comment made and provides boolean if it has been read or not

**Underlying structure**

**Table Documents** 
PK = id

**Table DocumentComments**
PK = id
FK = DocumentId
InResponseTo = UserId of the user who's comment has been responded to by inserting comment
OwnerId = UserId of the user who owns or created this comment

**Table Notifications** (Bears no direct relationship with DocumentComments since this table is a generic table that holds many types of notifications, not just DocumentComment notifications

PK = id
FK = RecieverId = The UserId of the user who will be receiving this notification.
CommentID = if the notification deals with a comment this value will be filled with the comment in question

AnnouncementID = if the notification deals with an announcement this value will be filled with the announcement in question

EventID
MeetingID = Both of these fields work the same as the above two fields.

Read = boolean, read state of the notification

Comment: Is `@DocumentId` the value of `InResponseTo`?

Comment: No. I will update my question above with a bit of my table structure and explanation. I am confusing myself right now just thinking about it.

Comment: @techdo `@DocumentId` is the PK of the Document that the comment currently being inserted is tied to. So what I am doing in that sql query is grabbing all ownerids(people who have written comments) from the DocumentComments table for a certain document. Hence the   `@DocumentId`.  So basically every comment inserted into the table DocumentComments holds the parent documentId as well as the userid of the person who wrote the comment. Hope this makes more sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, try this:

```
SET @Comid = (SELECT id FROM inserted);

INSERT INTO Notifications
([CommentID],[Type],[RecieverId])
SELECT @Comid, 'DocumentComment',OwnerId FROM DocumentComments WHERE DocumentID = @DocumentId
```

Comment: Awesome!It was so simple I feel embarrassed.